# IOS Localizing Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push, emoji

When I was prototyping for push notifications I had a php script with a non localized string pushed to the iphone, here I could also include emoji symbols.

I have now made a webservice using asp.net and I localize the push notifications on the IOS side.

But I cant seem to get emoji symbols to work now, Ive tried every combination og unicode escape
sequences in the localized string, and also tried sending the emoji as an argument in the push notification and having it included in the localized string "%@" and "%C" but to no luck.

Im stuck atm, so any tip to put me back on track is very much appriciated

Stefan

Comment: Did my answer help? Otherwise you could post your code how you create the push notification data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), characters that are not part of the "Basic Multilingual Plane" can be escaped using a UTF-16 surrogate pair.

For example the emoji symbol "THUMBS UP SIGN" is Unicode codepoint `U+1F44D`, and the UTF-16 surrogate pair for this is

```
0xD83D, 0xDC4D
```

The JSON Unicode escape sequence would be

```
\ud83d\udc4d
```

If you include this in the alert part of the push notification payload, the symbol will be correctly displayed (I have tested it).

But you can also use UTF-8, for the "THUMBS UP SIGN" this would be the bytes

```
0xF0, 0x9F, 0x91, 0x8D
```

Comment: Did anybody try pushing the 4-byte UTF-8 version? Doesn't seem to work here, will try the escaped approach. Shame to use up 12 bytes though.

Comment: @StefanL: I am quite sure that I tested it with the UTF-8 sequence also and that it worked.

Comment: I can confirm that the 4-byte UTF-8 approach actually _does_ work. Reportedly sending quoted surrogate-pairs like "\uD83D\uDC27" (haven't seen detailed log of bytes actually sent) cause them to arrive as plain-text at the other end, could be due to being upper-case instead of lower-case?

Comment: @StefanL: No, uppercase should be OK. I cannot test this at the moment as I am working on other projects currently.